# jStorage- TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, jstorage

I have installed jquery and jStorage as `npm i --save jstorage` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/jstorage) and `npm i --save jQuery`. I am trying to use jStorage and set value but getting error as :-

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined
```

## App.js

```
import $ from 'jquery'; 

const App = props => {
  const swithHandle = (function () {
    console.log('hi'); // correct output
    //  localStorage.setItem('rememberMe', '323232dd');  // correct output
    $.jStorage.set("mykey", "keyvalue");   //TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined
  }());
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App" onClick={swithHandle()}>
        <Navbar />
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Comment: As you seem to have installed jStorage on its own, have you tried importing it directly from the packages? (instead of trying to use it through jQuery)

Comment: No, I am new to ReactJs. Please suggest some solution.

Comment: I'm not sure if it would work but try `import jStorage from 'jstorage';` and then use it directly: `jStorage.set(...)` without `$`.

Comment: No its not working, already tried.

Comment: What error do you get when you do that?

Comment: When jQuery not used   error as   ./src/App.js
Cannot find file: 'jstorage.js' does not match the corresponding name on disk: '.\node_modules\jStorage\jstorage'.  When jQuery used and inporting jStorage then error is same as above mentioned.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218503/discussion-between-manz-and-ghassen-louhaichi).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [jStorage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jstorage) library seems to be saving itself globally in the page, and it seems to have no ties with the actual jQuery library through its typical name `$`.

Thus, the following code sample explains how to use both of them in your application:

```js
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'jstorage';

// this is how you use jQuery
$('#some_element').val();

// this is how you use jStorage
window.$.jStorage.set('a', 'b');
```

Please keep in mind that `window.$` is ***not*** jQuery.

And to further avoid confusion, if you intend to use jQuery itself, I suggest you name its import something different than `$`, for example:

```js
import jQuery from 'jquery';

jQuery('#some_element').val();
```